# Create Pivot from already existing PivotCache

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I want to create a new PivotTable based on the data that was used to create another PivotTable in another workbook.

I've realized the following stuff:
1.) Open the Workbook that holds data
2.) Copy the worksheet containing the PivotTable to the new Workbook

And now I want to access the Cache from the existing PivotTable and create a new one on a different Worksheet in the same Workbook. Therefore I'm using the following code:
    Set input_pivot_sheet = input_workbook.Worksheets("Worksheetbblabla")

```
'Select right Pivot Table
Set pivot_table = input_pivot_sheet.PivotTables(2)

'Create new Excel file
Set temp_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Add
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

'Create supportive Pivot by copying content from old file to new file
input_pivot_sheet.Copy After:=temp_excel_workbook.Sheets(1)
Set pivot_cache = pivot_table.PivotCache
'Create new Pivot out of this pivot...
Set worksheet_1 = temp_excel_workbook.Sheets(1)
new_pivot_table = pivot_cache.CreatePivotTable(worksheet_1.Range("A1"))
```

This code is failing since I get an Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument in this line:

```
new_pivot_table = pivot_cache.CreatePivotTable(worksheet_1.Range("A1"))
```

How can I access the data from the other PivotTable and plot a new PivotTable on another worksheet?

Comment: `Set new_pivot_table = pivot_cache.CreatePivotTable(worksheet_1.Range("A1"))`. Since a pivtotable is an object, you must `Set` it to assign it.

Comment: Thought so, but missing `Set` will give error 91, not error 5.

Comment: You can't use a pivotcache with different parent i.e Workbook.

Comment: Cyboashu- you nailed it. You cannot create PivotTables in other Workbooks; but you can create them in new worksheets in the same Workbook. I adapted my code, see comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of cyboashu's comment (you can find it as a comment at the question post) I adapted my code a little bit:

```
     'Switch to right Worksheet - Attention if "blablabka" is renamed...!!!!
    Set input_pivot_sheet = input_workbook.Worksheets("blabla")

    'Create new Excel file
    Set temp_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Add
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

    'Create supportive Pivot by copying content from old file to new file
    input_pivot_sheet.Copy After:=temp_excel_workbook.Sheets(1)

    'Close old file & newly created one
    input_workbook.Close
    temp_excel_workbook.SaveAs Filename:=temp_excel_file_name
    temp_excel_workbook.Close

    'Open new Excel... - not performant...
    Set temp_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Open(temp_excel_file_name)

    'Select right Pivot Table
    Set pivot_table = temp_excel_workbook.Sheets(2).PivotTables(2)
    Set pivot_cache = pivot_table.PivotCache
    'Create new Pivot out of this pivot...
    Set worksheet_1 = temp_excel_workbook.Sheets(1)
    new_pivot_table = pivot_cache.CreatePivotTable(worksheet_1.Range("A1"))
```

Now I can add the fields and rows. Thank you all!